# How To Display Customers Even If They Have No Sales (results)

Tags: sql

I have a code that pulls all of a Reps new customers and their year to date sales. The only problem is it only pulls customers that have sales in the invdate range, but I need it to show all of the accounts with a 0 if they do not have any sales. Is there any way to achieve this? I tried using COALESCE and it didn't seem to work. I also tried using left, right, full outer joins. Any help would be appreciated!

```
select 
a.Acctnum,  
sum(a.invtotal) as total 
from invoices a right join accounts b on a.acctnum = b.acctnum where 
a.invdate between '1/1/2017' and '12/31/2017'
and a.sls = '78'
and b.sls = '78'
and b.activetype = 'y' and b.startdate > (getdate()-365)
group by a.acctnum
order by total desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You are restricting your results in your WHERE clause *AFTER* you join your table causing records to drop. Instead, switch to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with your `accounts` table driving the query. Then restrict your `invoices` table in your `ON` clause so that `invoices` are dropped *BEFORE* you join.

```
SELECT a.Acctnum,
    sum(a.invtotal) AS total
FROM accounts b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN invoices a ON
        a.accntnum = b.acctnum AND
        --Put the restrictions on your left most table here
        --so they are removed BEFORE joining. 
         a.invdate BETWEEN '1/1/2017' AND '12/31/2017'
        AND a.sls = '78'
WHERE
    b.sls = '78'
    AND b.activetype = 'y'
    AND b.startdate > (getdate() - 365)
GROUP BY a.acctnum
ORDER BY total DESC
```

It's a bit like doing a subquery in `invoices` before joining in as the left table. It's just easier to drop the conditions into the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you where clauses are changing the right join to an inner join. Put all the ones that are aliased by a. into the ON clause.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to make sense. But what exactly do you mean by putting them into the ON clause?

Comment: See @JNevill's answer.